# Node horseman not working on AngularJS select options

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, node-horseman

I am trying to change AngularJS based select options using horseman.
Unfortunately, it is not working out for me.
The website is: https://www.cars.com/
I can't seem to change the make, model, price drop downs.

```
  horseman
  .userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36')
  .open('https://www.cars.com/').catch(function(error){console.log(error)})
  .select('div.sw-input-group-make > select', car.make)
  .wait(5000)
  .select('.sw-input-group-model > select', car.model)
  .select('.sw-input-group-price > select', car.price)
  .type('.zip-field',car.zipcode)
  .screenshot("C:/Users/Himanshu/Desktop/upwork/car/big1.png").log()
  .click('.sw-input-group-submit >input').catch(function(error){console.log(error)})
  .waitForNextPage().catch(function(error){console.log(error)})
  .screenshot("C:/Users/Himanshu/Desktop/upwork/car/big.png").log()
  .close();
});
```